# AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button even though it's not an ImageButton

Tags: android

I'm getting an error that I can't understand:

```
07-19 22:14:50.750 23192-23192/com.example.shun.zeatbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shun.zeatbeta, PID: 23192
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shun.zeatbeta/com.example.shun.zeatbeta.ReauthenticateActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.example.shun.zeatbeta.ReauthenticateActivity.onCreate(ReauthenticateActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Line that crashes program in activity:

```
private Button loginButton;

loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
```

**activity_reauthenticate2.xml:**

```
<com.example.shun.zeatbeta.ComfortaaButton
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_blue"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/facebookWrapper"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textFields" />
```

**ComfortaaButton.java**

```
package com.example.shun.zeatbeta;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class ComfortaaButton extends AppCompatButton {
    public ComfortaaButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public ComfortaaButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public ComfortaaButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf, 1);
    }

}
```

Why am I getting this error? The button is clearly a `Button`, not an `ImageButton`. I've tried cleaning project, restarted, clearing cache, etc. I even tried creating a new activity and layout file, and the error came back!

UPDATE: I got this info for the line in activity crashing the code:

```
Unexpected cast to AppCompatButton: layout tag was ImageButton (Id bound to an ImageButton in activity_landing_page.xml) less... (⌘F1) 
Keeps track of the view types associated with ids and if it finds a usage of the id in the Java code it ensures that it is treated as the same type.
```

So it seems like it looks for activities by id in activity_landing_page.xml instead of in activity_reauthenticate2.xml. Why? How can I change that?

**the app gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.s.company"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, except of course the init portion of the ComfortaaButton where you set the font which I commented out

Comment: @mTak I recreated the class with font and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

There must be are other duplicate id for your `loginButton`. Just make sure that you will get the correct import when you type `R.id.loginButton` from `loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);` for your target Activity or xml.

Comment: How do I make sure?

Comment: Type again the code `findViewById(R.id.loginButton)`, but before you enter loginButton, check or wait for suggestion if there is other choices for the id loginButton.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Button should also work fine.

Initiating the view as AppCompatButton,

```java
private AppCompatButton mLoginButton;

mLoginButton=findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
```

Comment: Tried `private AppCompatButton loginButton;         loginButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);` and I got `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`. `AppCompatButton` is a subclass of `Button`, so I think my code should work...

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle ?

Comment: @Sahand I am unable to reproduce the issue, I have created a custom button as you. Both Button and AppCompatButton works fine for me. Yes you are right, Button should work as well. Can you post the complete xml (Also you can remove the project level gradle file)

Comment: @Sahand are you trying to do any Constraint Layout animation or doing layout change through constraint sets?